# My React app isn't rendering the page right, it just shows a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I'm following a [YouTube video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soxd_xdHR0o). I have the Django API setup and working. But I ran into an issue with the React frontend I can't figure out. React is rendering a blank white page when I run "npm start". Here's my Header.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    appBar: {
        borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    },
}));


function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar
                position="static"
                color="white"
                elevation={0}
                className={classes.appBar}
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
                        BlogmeUp
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Here's my App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here's my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import './index.css';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';


const routing = (
    <Router>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I installed react-router-dom@5.0 so I could avoid issues with using `<Switch>`, could that be part of the problem? Please help!!

Update: according to the tutorial, the rendered page should look like this:
[image: React default page with a header]

Comment: how is your index.html looking? was this working before but now not working after you upgraded the `react-router-dom` version?

Comment: According to the tutorial, it should render the default React page, with a header at the top that has the word "BlogmeUp" shown in the upper left. I have an index.html file in the Django templates folder, but it just has a placeholder text that reads "// index", which is supposed to be shown in the upper left with no styling. I don't see either one of these.